# print environment variables sorted by name including variables with newlines

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I couldn't find an existing answer to this specific case: I would like to simply display all exported environment variables sorted by their name.  Normally I can do this like simply like:

```
$ env | sort
```

However, if some environment variables contain newlines in their values (as is the case on the CI system I'm working with), this does not work because the multi-line values will get mixed up with other variables.

Comment: with bash, you can probably do: `env -0 | while IFS= read -r -d ''; do printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"; done`

Comment: That wouldn't sort them though.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sort unfortunately.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Answering my own question since I couldn't find this elsewhere:

```
$ env -0 | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

`env -0` separates each variable by a null character (which is more-or-less how they are already stored internally).  `sort -z` uses null characters instead of newlines as the delimiter for fields to be sorted, and finally `tr '\0' '\n'` replaces the nulls with newlines again.

Note: `env -0` and `sort -z` are non-standard extensions provided by the GNU coreutils versions of these utilities.  Open to other ideas for how to do this with POSIX `sort`--I'm sure it is possible but it might require a for loop or something; not as easy as a one-liner.

Comment: My sort doesn't have -z option, what should I do?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `-z` option is a non-standard extension for both `env` and `sort`; the BSD implementations, in particular, do not support it.

Comment: Doesn't work in busybox (Alpine Linux).

Comment: Works in an Alpine 3.15 container (busybox). Does not work in earlier versions of Alpine (3.13, 3.14), see my answer below for a solution to this.

Answer (score 15):

The bash builtin `export` prints a sorted list of envars:

```
export -p | sed 's/declare -x //'
```

Similarly, to print a sorted list of exported functions (without their definitions):

```
export -f | grep 'declare -fx' | sed 's/declare -fx //'
```

Comment: Well done.  Maybe change the sed pattern to include a begin of line char `sed 's/^export //g` and do a global substitution

Comment: Nice, Im amazed I didn't find that before.

Answer (score 4):

```
env | sort -f
```

Worked for me.

The -f option makes sort ignore case, which is what you probably want 99% of the time

Comment: The question here was about sorting environment variables in the case where some variables contain multi-line values, in which case `sort` alone can't handle it because it will sort those lines like any other.

Answer (score 1):

In a limited environment where `env -0` is not available, eg. Alpine 3.13, 3.14 (commands are simplified busybox versions) you can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (K in ENVIRON) { printf "%s=%s%c", K, ENVIRON[K], 0; }}' | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

This uses `awk` to print each environment variable terminated with a `null`, simulating `env -0`.   Note that setting ORS to null (`-vORS='\0'`) does not work in this limited version of awk, neither does directly printing `\0` in the printf, hence the `%c` to print `0`.
Busybox awk lacks any sort functions, hence the remainder of the answer is the same as the top one.